# Regular Expression with optional elements in input string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

Can anyone give me the regular expression for currency which have the following formats :

```
1000 - valid
1,000 - valid
1,000.00 or 1000.00 - valid.
```

This means, the number **May or May Not** contain a comma(,) separator every 3 digits.

The number **May Or May Not** contain a dot (.), and if it carries a dot(.) it should show atleast 1 number after the decimal place.

And lastly it should be numerical characters only. If I need to make my question clear kindly suggest.

Comment: I tried without regular expressions. But i have no idea on building regular expressions.

Comment: @RanjanSarma: http://www.regular-expressions.info/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/^\d{1,3}(?:(?:,\d{3})*|(?:\d{3})*)(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

"Between one and three digits, then any number of groups of three digits prefixed by a comma *or* any number of groups of three digits not prefixed by said comma (disallowing a mix of the two kinds of groups), then an optional group of one or two digits prefixed by a dot."

Note: This regex assumes that you want to validate an entire string against the criteria outlined in your question. If you want to use it to find such numbers in a longer string, you will need to remove  the `^` and `$` from the beginning and end of the expression.

Comment: This will also match `"1,000000.00"`, I doubt this is desirable.

Comment: @tdammers: Good point. I have updated the regex to handle that case.

Comment: @NamidaAneskans: Kindly update the above expression with the fix for tdammers' bug I need it urgent. Thanking you.

Comment: @Ranjan: That's not how it works here. We gladly **help** you but we don't do your work or fullfil requests. In that case you'd have to *hire* someone.

Comment: @FelixKling: I apologize all of you for that. I am grateful to all of you and especially Namida for his guidance. I just requested him to update it as i am in situation.

Answer (score 1):

Something like so should work: `(,?\d{3})+(\.\d{2})?`. The regex will attempt to match a sequence of 3 digits precedeed by an optional comma, which is then, finally followed by an optional decimal point and 2 digits.

Please refer to [this](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) tutorial for more information.

EDIT: As per the comment below, the above regex can fail. I would recommend first using this regular expression: `^[\d][\d.,]+$` to make sure that you only have digits, thousand and decimal seperators. This regular expression will also make sure that the number starts with a digit, not with anything else. You could most likely have one regular expression which does everything, but it will most likely be quite complex.

Comment: It would not match `1,000.00` but for example `,999.00`.

Comment: No, it won't work. This will, for example, match `"pizza,123.123pizza!OMG"` and `",123123123,123.22"`, but not `"1.50"`.

Comment: @FelixKling: It *would* match 1,000.00, there is no `^` there.

Comment: @tdammers: It should be fixed now.

Comment: @FelixKling: It should be fixed now.